# Get Control values of datalist in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a datalist and I am calling javascript on div click added in datalist ..
How can i get control values on click of my div added in datalist

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
           <div id="metroaqui" class="divsub" runat="server" 
                onclick="javascript:getvalues(this);">
                <table>
                     <tr class="clstd">
                         <td>
                            <b>IP NO:-</b>
                          </td>
                          <td colspan="2" style="width: 20%">
                              <asp:Label runat="server" ID="ipnolable" 
                                   Text='<%# Eval("IpNo") %>'></asp:Label>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                              <b>PATIENT NO:-</b>
                          </td>
                          <td colspan="2">
                              <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1"
                                   Text='<%# Eval("PatientNo") %>'>
                              </asp:Label>
                           </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                       </tr>




</asp:DataList>
```

Comment: your `tr` and `div` is not properly closed.

Answer (score 0):

To access the control inside the DataList, try to use the following way,

```
function getVal() 
{
  var datalist = document.getElementById('<%=DataList1.ClientID%>').childNodes[0]; 
  var tb = datalist.getElementsByTagName("input"); 

  for (var i=0;i<tb.length;i++) 
  {
    //TextBox
    if (tb[i].type=="text") 
    {
    alert(tb[i].value);
    }

    //DropDown
    if (tb[i].type=="select") 
    {
    alert(tb[i].options[tb[i].selectedIndex].value);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: there is no control of type input in his question.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use `document.getElementById` to get the values from your controls.
Note that you id's will change at runtime.

Also remember that `label` render as `span` on browser so you will have to check for `innerText` and `innerHtml` of your control.

You can take benefit of `ClientIDMode="static"` for static client id of the server controls. like `asp:Label` etc.